# First negative integer in every window of size k with auxiliary space O(1) and O(n) time complexity

Tags: java, sliding-window

Given an array and a positive integer k, find the first negative integer for each window(contiguous subarray) of size k. If a window does not contain a negative integer, then print 0 for that window.

```
package com.slidingwindow;

public class demo2 {


    public static void  maximum(int arr[], int k) {
        int index = -1;
        boolean flag = false;

        int i = 0, j = 0, sum = 0;

        while (j < arr.length) {
            
        if(arr[j]<0 && !flag) {
            index =j;
            flag = true;
            System.out.println(arr[index]);
        }
        
            
            if (j - i + 1 < k) {
                j++;
                
            } else if (j - i + 1 == k) {
                
                if(!flag) {
                    System.out.println("0");
                    i++;
                    j++;
                }else {
                    //slide window by incrementing i and j
                    i++;
                    j++;
                    flag = false;a
                }
                
                
            }
        }

    

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { -2, 5, 1, 8, -2, 9, -1 };
        int k = 2;
        maximum(arr, k);
        

    }

}
```

**Expected output**

-2

0

0

-2

-2

-1

**Actual**

-2

0

0

-2

0

-1

Comment: You only have a single loop. Imagine a window of 4, and trace how your program would go over two consecutive windows. It wouldn't, your logic is flawed, and the failure you see is an artifact of this. When you slide the window, where do you check the beginning of the windows again? You need two nested loops.

Comment: @PetrJaneček Not true, one loop is enough. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to understand your logic, but I couldn't quite get it.  Here's what I came up with, starting pretty much from scratch:

```
class demo2 {

    public static void maximum (int arr[], int k){
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length - k + 1; j++) {
            boolean found = false;
            for (int x = j; x < j + k; x++) {
                if (arr[x] < 0) {
                    System.out.println(arr[x]);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
                System.out.println(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { -2, 5, 1, 8, -2, 9, -1 };
        int k = 2;
        maximum(arr, k);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
-2
0
0
-2
-2
-1
```

I recognize that there might be a more efficient way of doing this to the point that it would matter, if both the array length and the window size were significantly large.  But your question doesn't state that this is the case. This is a place where you need to be sure you want to spend the time to optimize beyond the simple and obvious solution.

Comment: Notice that you have two loops, obviously, while the OP does only have one.

Comment: So?  It doesn't say that he needs to solve the problem with just a single loop.

Comment: I want to do the same in O(n) complexity and O(1) auxiliary space

Comment: @coder25 That means you'll need to bring in some smart tricks. Right now your algorithm is flawed, when the window slides it simply ignores all the elements of the window except for the first one. Increase your k to 3 or more to easily see that. I'd start with Steve's version and improve from that, there are massive optimization opportunities.
To get O(n) and constant extra space, you'll need a something like this: Go through the array, write out 0s if needed, an as soon as you find a negative, compute how many windows that covers, write out, then carefully continue.

Comment: @coder25, this is O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity. The inner loop is of constant iteration count, so doubling the size of the input data only doubles the size of the outer loop and therefore doubles the time.   I make no copies of the data or otherwise use anything but a set number of variables.

Comment: @PetrJaneček - I just noticed your comment above.  Why do you think my code is not O(n) time and O(1) space complex? - I propose that any optimization will not change the time complexity, but will only decrease the time by a constant multiple since it would just be working to avoid the extra work in each constant-width iteration that is the inner loop.

Comment: @Steve Oh, yeah, no, you're absolutely right, this is O(n*k) which is linear with increasing n and is completely fine. I'm embarrassed I missed that, nice.

Comment: O(n) and O(n * k) are not the same. Both parameters, n and k, are input parameters, so, in terms of input parameters, this algorithm has O(n * k) complexity, which is polynomial not linear.

Comment: @Mafor - Thats not true at all.  O(n) is O(n). It asks the question, "how does the time increase as n increases....period".  It doesn't address the issue of two variables increasing. To involve 'k', you'd have to rewrite it as a function of 'n'.  If 'k' is going to change too, then we have to be able to define how it changes as 'n' changes.  If we can write 'k' as a function of 'n', then you can get rid of 'k' and you have your new O(?).  So yes, if 'k' increases linearly with 'n', then you have O(n*n) or O(n^2).  But we don't know that. - The question is phrased like 'k' is a constant

Comment: Well, let me rephrase. OP never said he was interested in the complexity relative to the n only. He said the complexity needs to be O(n), period. O(n*k) does not fulfill this requirement.

Comment: @Mafor - Again, O(n) involves one variable, by definition.  There's no such thing as O(n*k).  So if the OP expects 'k' to change with 'n', they have to explain how it changes with 'n' for it to make any sense to state O(n) as a requirement.  Lacking that information,  stating O(n) DEFINES the problem as only having one quantity changing.  That quantity is usually the size of the input dataset, so it makes sense to assume in this case that 'k' is constant.

Comment: ...and this is all academically silly, of course.  What we should do is get a better explanation of the problem...of what 'k' is.  Or, the OP can just go with your algorithm and know they are covered either way.  I don't doubt that your alg, if it does what it says, is "better" than mine.  If it works for the OP, then all is well.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/30036/can-a-big-oh-time-complexity-contain-more-than-one-variable

Comment: Thanks.  The last paragraph of that answer makes my point, which is that your alg is no more or less O(n) than mine is:  "As far as whether you can call them () time, no, of course not -- unless you somehow know that =(). Of course, if you know that =(), then it follows that +=(), so an (+) time algorithm is also an () time algorithm. But if there is no guarantee that =(), then you cannot call it an () time algorithm.".

Comment: Ok, I must admit: formally you are right. Your algorithm is O(n) and O(k), the other one is O(n) and O(1) in regard to k.

Answer (score 0):

It can be implemented with real linear complexity **O(n)** (as opposite to the naive implementation with <s>polynomial</s> complexity **O(n*k)**):

```java
public static void maximum (int arr[], int k) {
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (index >= i + k) {
            index = -1;
        }
        if (arr[i] < 0) {
            index = i;
        }
        arr[i] = index >= 0 ? arr[index] : 0;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= arr.length - k; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** or even better, without writing to the `arr` array:

```java
public static void maximum (int arr[], int k) {
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - k + 1; i++) {
        if(index < i) {
            // Find the index of the next negative number
            do {
                index++;
            } while (index < arr.length && arr[index] >= 0);
        }
        // If the next negative number is within the window print it,
        // otherwise print "0"
        System.out.println(index < i + k ? arr[index] : 0);
    }
}
```

Comparison with the naive algorithm O(n*k) in terms of the number of iterations of the (internal) loop (worst case scenario, i.e. when there are no negative numbers in the table at all):

```
            | naive        | dynamic |
            | O((n-m+1)*m) | O(n)    |
--------------------------------------
  n=7,  m=2 |           12 |       7 |
 n=10,  m=2 |           18 |      10 |
n=100, m=10 |          910 |     100 |
n=100, m=50 |         2550 |     100 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a c++ solution, also i have submitted this code on gfgs practice problem and it got accepted. Time complexity is O(n) and auxiliary space complexity is O(K)

```
vector<int> firstNegative(vector<int> arr, int lenn, int k)
{
  vector <int> ans;
  int start = 0, end = 0;
  queue <int> index;
  while(start <= lenn-k)
  {
    if(arr[end] < 0)
      index.push(end);

      
    if(k == (end-start+1))
    {
      if(index.empty())
        ans.push_back(0);
      else
      {
        if(index.front()>=start && index.front()<=end)
          ans.push_back(arr[index.front()]);
        else
        {
          index.pop();
          continue;
        }
      }
      start++;
    }
    end++;
  }
  return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     Deque<Long> queue = new LinkedList<>();
     int C=N-K+1;
        long[] output = new long[C];
        int c = -1;
        int startWindow = 0;
        int endWindow =K;
        boolean firstFlag=true;
        while (true) {
            for(int j=startWindow;j<endWindow;j++){
                if(A[j] < 0 && firstFlag){
                  //  queue.add(A[j]);
                  if(c<C-1){
                    output[++c]=A[j];
                  }
                    firstFlag=false;
                    break;
                }
                if(j>=N-1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(firstFlag){
                if(c<C-1){
                    output[++c]=0;
                  }
              //  queue.add((long)0);
            }
            if(endWindow>=N){
                break;
            }
            firstFlag=true;
            startWindow=startWindow+K-1;
            endWindow=startWindow+K;
        }
//      while(!queue.isEmpty())
//            output[++c] = queue.remove();
        return output;
```

Comment: The answer does not satisfy the requirement to have time complexity of O(n) as you have a for loop inside a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
function one_loop() {

    $arr = [-12, -1, 7, -8, 15, 30, -16, -30, 40, 3];
    $arr_len = count($arr); // 7
    $result = [];
    $k = 2;
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;

    while ($j < $arr_len && $i < $arr_len-$k+1) {       
        $flag = false;
        $window_size = $j-$i+1;
        if($arr[$j] < 0) {
            array_push($result, $arr[$j]);
            $flag = true;
        }
        if($window_size == $k && $flag == false){
            array_push($result, 0);
            $i++;
            $j = $i;
        } elseif ($flag == true) {
            $i++;
            $j = $i;
        } elseif ($flag == false && $window_size != $k) {
            $j++;
        }
    }
    echo implode($result, ", ");
}
```